# Log every time iPhone switches type of cellular network?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there an easy way to make a log of every time an iPhone switches to a different type of cellular network?  I have noticed what seems like odd behavior on my phone with very frequent switching between networks, even while stationary.  I would like to create an application that I can run in the background on my phone which will make a log including timestamp, location, and type of network (3G, LTE, etc) but I am not certain where to start.